# Deciding on an algorithm for 'Jumping Jack'

Tags: algorithm

A while back in a programming competition I encountered a puzzling problem, and it has bothered me since. Although I do not remember it verbatim, I will do my best to reproduce it:

> Jack starts at 0 on the number line and jumps one unit in either direction. Each successive jump he makes is longer than the previous by 1 unit, and can be made in either direction. Write a program that takes a number and returns the minimum number of jumps Jack makes to reach that number.

I apologise in advance if this is not deemed a good question, or if the title is deemed misleading.

Comment: Correct word would be 'knapsack problem'

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Really, what have you got so far ?  Work through the first few jumps with pencil and paper, or your favourite calculator program, and a pattern emerges.

Comment: Is overshoot OK?  If your target number is **2**, is getting to **3** OK?

Comment: @DhruvPathak - I'm not sure if knapsack really applies to this, because the set of numbers to work with are not fixed in advance.  You could use +1 or -1, but not both, +2 or -2, but not both, etc.

Comment: @angelatlarge it seems to me that you must have to land on the exact number, or else this would be quite easy.

Comment: @BloonsTowerDefence: so we assume than that some numbers are unreachable (e.g. **2**)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @angelatlarge: 2 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 - 4

Comment: Oh, right. For some reason I read the question doubling the jump size, not +1.  Thanks!

Comment: @angelatlarge: one thing you're missing is that Jack can reach any finite integer in a finite number of jumps.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Is there a proof you can link to for that?  Certainly seems true.

Comment: @angelatlarge you could reach 2 via [1, -2, 3]

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Nevermind, supercat's answer makes it clear why that is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd like to elaborate on @supercat's correct and fast solution and describe an algorithm that computes a minimal length sum in addition to computing the length of such a sum.

### Algorithm

Find the least integer k such that t_k := 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k >= |n| and t_k has the same parity as |n|.
Then flip the signs of the summands of t_k in a systematic way to total n.

Here are the details.
Notice that t_k = k(k + 1)/2, a triangular number.
Setting t_k = |n| and solving for k gives the ceiling of (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8|n|))/2.
So k equals the ceiling or 1 or 2 plus it, whichever of those three numbers has the same parity as n and is least.
Here we're using the fact that the set {t, t + s, t + s + (s + 1)} of three consecutive triangular numbers contains both even and odd numbers for any positive integers t, s. 
(Simply check all four parity possibilities for t and s.)

To find a minimal length sum for n, first compute d := (t_k - n)/2.
Because t_k >= |n| and t_k and n have the same parity, d lies in the set {0, 1, 2, ..., t_k}.
Now repeatedly subtract: d = a_k (k) + r_k, r_k = a_{k-1} (k-1) + r_{k-1}, ..., r_2 = a_1 (1) + r_1, choosing each a_i maximally in {0, 1}.
By the lemma below,  r_1 = 0.
So d = sum_{i=1}^k a_i i.
Thus n = t_k - 2d = sum_{i=1}^k i - sum_{i=1}^k 2a_i i = sum_{i=1}^k (1 - 2a_i) i and 1 - 2a_i lies in {-1, 1}.
So the sequence b_i := 1 - 2a_i is a path, and by the minimality of k, b_i is a minimal path.

### Algorithm example

Consider the target number n=12. According to Algorithm 3, the possibilities for k are 5, 6, or 7. The corresponding values of t_k are 15, 21, and 28. Since 28 is the least of these with the same parity as n, we see that k=7. So d = (t_k - n)/2 = 8, which we write as 1 + 7 according to the algorithm. Thus a shortest path to 12 is -1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 - 7.

I say *a* shortest path, because shortest paths aren't unique in general.
For example, 1 + 2 -3 + 4 - 5 + 6 + 7 also works.

### Algorithm correctness

Lemma: Let A_k = {0, 1, 2, ..., t_k}. 
Then a number lies in A_k if and only if it can be expressed as a sum sum_{i=1}^k a_i i for some sequence a_i in {0, 1}.

Proof: By induction on k.
First, 0 = sum_{i=1}^0 1, the empty sum.
Now suppose the result holds for all k - 1 >= 0 and suppose a number d lies in A_k.
Repeatedly subtract: d = a_k (k) + r_k, r_k = a_{k-1} (k-1) + r_{k-1}, ..., choosing each a_i = 0 or 1 maximally in {0, 1} and stopping when the first r_j lies in A_j for some j < k.
Then by the induction hypothesis, r_j = sum_{i=0}^j b_i i for some b_i in {0, 1}.
Then d = r_j + sum_{i=j+1}^k a_k i, as desired.
Conversely, a sum s := sum_{i=1}^k a_i i for a_i in {0,1} satisfies 0 <= s <= sum_{i}^k i = t_k, and so s lies in A_k.

### Algorithm time complexity

Assuming that arithmetic operations are constant time, it takes O(1) time to compute k from n, and hence the length of a minimal path to n.
Then it takes O(k) time to find a minimal length sum for d, then O(k) time to use that sum to produce a minimal length sum for n.
So O(k) = O(sqrt(n)) time all up.

Comment: +1. But why do you need all this? It target is T, and the Triangular number you found is U, don't you just need to flip the sign of (U-T)/2? btw, the question only asks for the number of jumps.

Comment: @Knoothe, no, consider our running example of T=12.  Then U=28, k=7, and (T - U)/2 = 8 > k. So there is no 8 bit to flip. Regarding the original question, oh yeah, you're right, we only need to find the length of the minimal path, which is k.  Still, finding a minimal path is a good question too :-)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I posted the comment. Thanks!

Comment: @araichev, nice reply, vote up! I am working on the same puzzle. A dumb question, what do you mean "triangular number" and why it is important t_k has the same parity as |n|? Appreciate for more details.

Comment: One of the best answers for this question

Answer (score 8):

For any number of jumps, one can easily compute the maximum positive distance the jack could travel.  Flipping the polarity of positive jumps totaling any particular value *k* will cause the jack to end up 2k counts below where it would have otherwise.  For any maximum distance *t*, and any non-negative *n* of the same parity (even if *t* is even; odd if *t* is odd) less than or equal to that distance, it will be possible to find a combination of jumps which totals *n*.  Thus, one need not worry about trees, knapsacks, or any other such things--just whether some number of jumps will be sufficient, and whether it will yield the correct "parity".

Comment: Could you give an example?  For instance, could you step through the calculation for the number of jumps to reach 12?

Comment: Four jumps could reach a maximum of ten (even, but too small).  Five jumps could reach a maximum of 15 (odd).  Six jumps 21 (also odd).  Seven jumps 28 (even, and large enough).  1+2-3+4-5+6+7 = 1+2+4+6+7 - 3-5 = 12.

Comment: Very clever, I never would have thought of that.

Comment: Nice reply, @supercat, vote up. If you could elaborate a bit more what do you mean "Flipping the polarity of positive jumps totaling any particular value k will cause the jack to end up 2k counts below where it would have otherwise" by an example, it will be great.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the sum of **n** consecutive integers is `n(n+1)/2`.  For example `1+2+3+4=10` =  `4*5/2=10`.  This is the minimum number of steps necessary to reach the target number.  But there might be overshoot.  Say the target is `11`. Four jumps will get you to `10` (we just calculated that), but `5` will get you to `5*6/2=15`.  Now we note only that in the case of 11, we jump back when step size is `2`, and we arrive at `11` correctly.  We'll deal with overshoot in more detail later. Back to how to calculate the number of jumps in the first place.  Our formula is `n(n+1)/2 = x` where `x` is the target number.  The [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) tells us that the solution to this is

```
(-1+/-sqrt(-1+8x)))/2
```

or

```
(-1-/+(sqrt(9x))/2
```

The negative "version" will always yield an imaginary number, which is irrelevant here so we have

```
(sqrt(9x) + 1)/2
```

Take the ceiling of that number and you have the initial number of jumps necessary.

Overshoot is a bit complicated. In our reaching `11` example, overshoot is `4` (`15-11=4`), so we just need to make the `+2` jump into `-2` jump, and that is the place to "stash" the 4 overshoot.  However, things are not always so simple: `12` can be reached via `-1-2+3+4-5+6+7`: it requires `7` steps, not `5` as predicted. The basic observation is that an overshoot must be **even**, otherwise there is no overshoot/2 step to take.  Here's how we find the number of steps for `12`

1. Using the above algorithm we find that the minimum number of steps is `5`, which gets us to `15`
2. Compute the overshoot: we have `3`.
3. If overshoot is odd (which it is in this case) try the next number of steps and go back to step 2, until you find an even overshoot.  This is your number of steps

For 12 therefore, we try `5` steps, yielding `15` and overshoot of `3`. Then we try six steps yielding `21` and an overshoot of `9`. Finally we try `7` steps yielding `28` and an overshoot of `16`. This is our minimum number of steps.  This can probably be computed by a formula, however.

Answer (score 1):

You could model Jack's progress as a binary tree, where the left node represents a jump backwards, and the right node represents a jump forward.

The value of each node is Jack's current position.

The depth of the node corresponds with the current jump length.

**Edit** - You can't prune a node that has the same value as a node higher in the tree, because the value of its children will be different, because it is at a different depth.

<strike>To keep the search space from growing too quickly, you'll want to aggressively prune any node whose value is a repeat of a previous node.</strike>

Also, the entire left subtree below the root can be pruned, because all of the values are the negation of the corresponding values in the right subtree. For example:

Right subtree:
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 - 4 = 2

Mirror image in left subtree:
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 + 4 = -2

Luckily, it seems like the tree generates lots of duplicates.  For example, at depth = 7, instead of 32 nodes (64/2, because we're only dealing with the right subtree), there appears to only be 6 distinct nodes:

```
4 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 + 6 - 7
14 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 - 7
16 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 + 7 
18 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 - 5 + 6 + 7
20 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 + 7
28 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7
```

All of the rest of the 32 possible combinations seem to be either positive numbers that are already higher up the tree, or negative numbers from the mirror image left subtree.

So I would do a breadth first search until I found the number I was looking for.

Comment: Why does your table not list zero, nor 2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 22, 24, or 26?

Comment: @supercat I was incorrectly thinking you could prune nodes that were a duplicate of higher nodes - see my edit.

Comment: Hmmm... that looks like it would work, but wouldn't the running time be something like O(2^n)?  (where n is the answer)

Comment: @Lorkenpeist - Correct.  supercat provided the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

Find the smallest `k` for which the sum of the first `k` positive naturals such that $k(k+1)/2 = a + b$, where $n = a - b$.

We have a system of equations:

- `k(k+1)/2 = a + b`
- `n = a - b`
- `a, b, k` are positive integers

There are three unknowns and only two equations. We can combine to get a target equation to satisfy:

- k(k+1) + 2n = 4a

We need to find the smallest positive `k` such that this solution can be satisfied for the given integer `n`, given that `a` has to be some positive integer. Let us note some things:

1. if `n` is even, then either `k` or `k+1` must be divisible by 4; i.e., `k = 0 or 3 mod 4`.
2. if `n` is odd, then neither `k` nor `k+1` can be divisible by 4; i.e., `k = 1 or 2 mod 4`.

This handles the part about all the numbers being integers. To handle the part about `k` and `a` being positive, we need to stipulate that

- `k >= floor(sqrt(2n))`

Phew. Now, for an example:

Say that n = 7. Then we know neither `k` nor `k+1` are divisible by 4. Similarly, we know that `k >= 4`. We may immediately skip `k = 4` since we know `k` is not divisible by 4. We may try `k = 5`; we get in our system:

```
n = 7
k = 5
a = 11
b = 4
```

These numbers all work, so we have a valid solution. We chose the solution in such a way that we had to find the one with smallest `k` first. If you cared to, you could even reconstruct the sequence of jumps Jack uses. In this case, it's easy: Jack jumps 11 to the right and 4 to the left. The only way to jump 4 left is to jump 1 left and 3 left. So jack jumps as follows:

```
----------J------N---
---------J-------N--- -1
-----------J-----N--- +2
--------J--------N--- -3
------------J----N--- +4
-----------------J--- +5
```

However, for your problem, once you find a `k` that works, you're done. You will not need to try many values of `k` before you find one that works.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for the amount j of numbers needed so that the sum from 1 to j is larger than the target number and of the same parity.

Here is a simple working code in python 2.7:

```
def numberOfJumps(n):
    n = abs(n)
    j = 0
    while True:
        s = j*(j+1)/2
        if s >= n and not (s - n)%2:
            break
        j += 1
    return j

for i in range(10):
    print i, numberOfJumps(i)
```

The problem can be simplified to positive numbers only because -n and n require the same amount of jumps. We simply have to jump in the opposite direction for each number in a sequence.

Then, to reach n, we have to make shure that the sum of only positive jumps reaches n or more.

We also have to make shure the parity of the sum is the same as the target number because jumping in the negative direction yields an even difference on the sum and therefore does not change its parity.

Say you jump 1+2+3+4+5 = 15, inverting any combination of numbers in the sequence yields an odd number so the difference is even.